# issue creating a list with basic python loop for a in b:

Tags: maya

I am trying to create a list in python that is filled with the elements I have selected in Autodesk Maya. However, when I select more than one element, this element gets duplicated. I thing this is a really simple issue because I'm not looping correctly and then an key gets added to my list more than once.
If someone with more knowledge could take a look and give me some advice would be great!
Many thanks in advance,

Joan

```
items = []
selectedObjects = cmds.ls(sl=True)
strItems = []
for item in selectedObjects:
    b = item.encode('utf-8')
    strItems.append(b)
    for item1 in strItems:
        lenItem = len(item1)
        lenItemNoGrp = lenItem - 5
        lenItemNoGrp2 = lenItem - 6
        grp = item1[lenItemNoGrp:lenItem]
        grp2 = item1[0:lenItemNoGrp2]
        grpName = grp2
        if grp == 'group':
            items.append({
                "type": "maya_file",
                "name": shotName + 'V' + versionStr + grpName,
            })
        else:
            None
```

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? What is the final output that you want? You really don't need 2 loops for this, and it's why you're getting duplicated items (the 2nd loop does this)

Answer (score 0):

You are looping over the complete content of strItem every time you add something to it. Let's say you have selected obj1 and obj2. Then

- obj1 is added to the list
- the second loop takes obj1 and does something with it
- the outer loop stars again and adds obj2 to the list
- the inner loop again takes all contents of the list and first takes obj1 and then obj2

So iterating over the canging list is maybe not what you want to do in this case.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you indented the loop by accident.  This version is still missing the variables `shotName` and `versionString` but it will not duplicate things

```
items = [] 
selectedObjects = cmds.ls(sl=True) 
strItems = [] 

for item in selectedObjects:
    b = item.encode('utf-8')
    strItems.append(b) 

for item1 in strItems:
    lenItem = len(item1)
    lenItemNoGrp = lenItem - 5
    lenItemNoGrp2 = lenItem - 6
    grp = item1[lenItemNoGrp:lenItem]
    grp2 = item1[0:lenItemNoGrp2]
    grpName = grp2
    if grp == 'group':
        items.append({
            "type": "maya_file",
            "name": shotName + 'V' + versionStr + grpName,
        })
```

However you can simplify this in a couple of ways.

1. You can do the utf-8 conversion with a list comprehension
2. You can also find the items ending in 'group' using `endswith`
3. You can use a negative slice to get the rest of the string without 'group'

That gets you down to:

```
group_nodes = [item.encode('utf-8') for item in cmds.ls(sl=True) if item.endswith('group')]
entries = [{ 
             'type':'maya_file', 
             'name': "{0}V{1}{2}".format(shotName, versionStr, entry[:-5])
            } 
           for entry in group_nodes]
```